# Помогите зациклить проверку файла в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Такая ситуация, есть текстовый файл, одна прога в нее пишет время от времени текст, надо этот текст читать и постить в ВК. Как это все дело зациклить чтобы постоянно шла проверка на появление новой строки в файле и отправка его в ВК?

```
import vk
token = "токен"
session = vk.Session(access_token=token)
api = vk.api.API(session, v='5.80', land='ru')
f = open('файл.txt')
for line in f:
    text=line,
api.wall.post(owner_id='группа вк', message=text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
position = 0
with open('file.txt') as fh:
    while True:
        fh.seek(position)
        data = fh.read()
        position = fh.tell()
        if data:
            api.wall.post(owner_id='группа вк', message=data)
```